# Where do I keep the application logic in an offline-first web app?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, architecture, couchdb, pouchdb

I'm trying to build an offline first web application using couchdb and pouchdb as the backend/frontend databases, AngularJS as the frontend framework and expressjs/nodejs as the backend server. The problem is that what I'm used to is the backend-MVC mindset of building web apps, and not to SPAs, offline-first design, or having only json apis on the application server.

The problem I see with the design I'm considering is that I don't see any role of the nodejs server except serving static files. The frontend would get data from the pouchdb database which would sync with the couchdb database backend. I need an offline-first application capable of working locally when there's no connectivity and syncing when connectivity is available, so this is important.

But where do I implement the important bits of application logic that I need in the backend, like form input validation or user access control? I found some ways to embed logic in couchdb databases (like using filters as shown [here](https://www.theodo.fr/blog/2014/11/how-to-build-web-applications-work-offline-pouchdb/)) but somehow writing application logic in the database doesn't feel right.

What part of the big picture am I missing here?

Comment: *writing application logic in the database doesn't feel right* Why? It is a backend, as any other. If it provides validation and access control, it is ok. If it doesn't, it's not.

Comment: @estus I didn't realize at first that CouchDB is capable of doing all those things that a regular backend does. I was thinking it was meant to be just a database. Now I see I was wrong.

Comment: Any way, it makes sense to put a thin security layer between DB and client. It may have the same API as CouchDB for convenience. Even if CouchDB does access control, I'm not sure if it can handle throttling, etc.

Comment: @estus But then you'd have to re-implement CouchDB's entire sync API, no?

Comment: Not necessarily. The middleware can just redirect all requests to CouchDB transparently but provide additional security measures (auth, throttling, blacklisted endpoints). I'm not sure if there are existing solutions that are up to date, but in its basic form the solution may be really simple. E.g. https://github.com/ammmir/express-couch-proxy